# Pandas: How to concat all cells of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Given that i have the below dataset, which contains column with `String` type.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dt = {
    "C1": ["A", "B", "B", "B", "A"],
    "C2": ["B", "A", "A", "B", "A"]
}

dt = pd.DataFrame(dt)

print(dt)
```

So, it looks like this

```
   C1  C2
0  A  B
1  B  A
2  B  A
3  B  B
4  A  A
```

I need to concate all the cells in each column and obtain a new dataset as below:

```
       C1
0  ABBBA
1  BAABA
```

How can i do it?

Comment: `dt.sum().reset_index(drop=True)`?

Comment: One addition to @Ch3steR answer: `dt.sum().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame(name=dt.columns[0])`

Comment: @Erfan  was just about to add that :P

Comment: If you want a different seperator, then use apply `df.apply(', '.join)`

Answer (score 0):

Ch3steR/Erfan's answer works for what you've asked:

```
dt = dt.sum().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame(name=dt.columns[0])
```

If you want the index to be C1, C2 etc, you can just do this:

```
cols_ = dt.columns
dt = dt.sum().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame(name = 'new_col_name')
dt.index = cols_
dt
```

Comment: Your second answer is a bit cumbersome, just use `dt.sum().to_frame(name='Col')`